# Can a circuit breaker become compromised by flooding?

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I often hear about home basements being flooded by several feet of water. Hypothetically, if the water line is high enough to submerge the outlets and the circuit breaker, can it not only short circuit the outlets, but short across the circuit breaker, turning the standing water into an elecution hazard?  If so, how can it be prevented?

Comment: You should have an even bigger breaker on the outside of the house

Comment: What if that's flooded too?

Comment: I want all the nasty and ugly  theoretical stuff, not meathead explanations like "don't step into the water stupid."

Comment: Perhaps submit your question to what-if.xkcd.com?

Comment: If you can guarantee the house was flooded with distilled water you may be ok. If it's real water you will have deposits of salts, minerals and who knows what else inside the breaker. Replacing them is pretty much compulsory.

Comment: It can be considered home improvement, but this is really an electricity question.

Comment: You should research: [residual current device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device).

Comment: LOL!  I guess my question is too meatheadish to be posted in the electrical engineering board.  Moderators of this QA should be offended.

Comment: It is an interesting question though that I have often found puzzling. The old dropping a toaster in the bathtub electrocution thing. If the case is properly grounded, how would enough electricity ever pass though the water to kill you.

Comment: @Trevor.  Yes, the case might be grounded if there is a 3 prong connector in which case you'll get cooked until the main breaker reacts.  If it is only a two pronger, you will cook until the amps blows the fuse. It is a matter of duration of the cooking. Also, the water more avenues for the current to reach your heart.

Comment: If the water gets high enough to reach the panel, and the water provides a low resistance path. It should trip the main breaker.  If the water gets up to the main feeder, and you don't have a breaker ahead of that. You'll either blow out the distribution transformer, or pop a cutout.

Comment: If your sewer line is in the basement, there may be other dangers lurking in the water.

Comment: A cutout or one of the panel knockouts? Sewer line?  Alligators, crocs or pythons? Methane?

Comment: @user148298 A [cutout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_cutout) is a device used to protect distribution wiring and devices (often used to protect transformers).

Comment: @Trevor as any EE solving a resistor puzzle can affirm, electricity follows all paths in proportion to their *conductivity*.  Conductivity is the inverse (literally) of resistivity.  If you are one of those paths, and it flows more than the ~5ma needed to stun you... You drown.

Comment: @Harper, yes I understand that, I'm an EE too, it just seems the short path through the toaster is so MUCH shorter than the path through the water/me/pipes that 5mA would be hard to obtain. Esp since the toaster casing becomes almost a faraday cage. But I'm not going to try it ;)

Comment: @Trevor Might be a good experiment for the MythBusters (if they're still around).

Comment: Wording nitpick: You mean an _electrocution_ hazard. An [elocution](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elocution) hazard would be something entirely different, like William Shatner.

Comment: That poor man.   @Trevor you presume the toaster has a wired ground wire to chassis, that would help a LOT but few are. The strategy with 2-prong appliances is to double-insulate them, but that does nothing in water.

Comment: @Harper, yes I know. My point was more of a thought experiment. Never a good idea in any situation since you are relying on the integrity of the grounding system which, by all accounts from other questions on here, is a really bad assumption to make when your life hangs on the balance ;)

Answer (score 2):

Watch for flood lines.  Yes, any breaker that's been underwater should be smashed (so others don't dig it out of the trash and use it).

If you can't find an uncorrupted main breaker to cut, call the power company at the "my power is out" number and they'll send someone over ASAP because they don't want you dead. Dead customers don't buy electricity.   However if this was a large scale incident, their plate will be very, very full and your request will get triage'd and done when feasible.   Obviously, in the meantime, stay away from it.

After the flood is gone you have to size up each component.  Panels are simple affairs and it might be possible to take it apart and clean it.  Conduit should be OK but I'd pull the wires out and disassemble it enough to clean the insides by pulling a rag through them.  Every junction box would have to be cleaned out.   The wires will be ok if they say THWN or other outdoor rating.   Ratings for outdoor wire presume the wire is immersed in water 24x7.   Keeping water out of outdoor conduit isn't really possible.

Romex will be junk.  Every receptacle, switch and machine of any kind will be junk.

Comment: What if GFI (aka)  RCCB or RCB breaker was put into each in breaker position ( one at a time) and showed no faults?  Junk everything if no insurance and poor?

Comment: @TonyStewart, if you can guarantee that subsequent drying internally does not lock the moving parts in place..... perhaps.

Comment: @TonyStewart They make a tool called a megger for that purpose.  Flood damage isn't *just* about water presence and insulation deterioration.  That least, I'd say.  It's also a lot about corrosion and other things that'll bite you on down the road.  Insurance and poverty have nothing to do with it; it's about the worth of a human life.

Comment: I am well aware of the tester and have done testing to 200kV on power transformers and have been in same room of a long blue corona discharge from a secondary arc from cottage roof thru DR table swag lamp thru table thru floor which lasted for >1/10 of second. Good thing we were not sitting under the table. The arc was 1m long or about 1 million volts even with grounded power entry pole.   No damage.. just a wake up call to nature.

Comment: I have seen more risks of DIY handymen reversing hot neutral in 2 or 3 way switches with hot faceplate screws or Neutral and ground reversed than flood damage risks, but near ocean water or salt spray and raises risks.   Partial Discharge leading to full BDV arc currents ought to safely trip a working breaker or  start a fire if breaker fails   Loose contact wires are a bigger risk.to fire damage but I hear you .safety can be measured but otherwise if not , play it safe. but Insulation and leakage protection testing is possibly cheaper than retail rip up and  replacement

Comment: 6kV arc protection in breakers may be compromised and may result in a breaker spark, just as a lightning transient that gets past the the <6kV spark gap in all power meters. Weak surface contaminants on bushings in damp morning occur every day outside due to condensation and the corona does NOT impact human life. It might be same inside a breaker or wire pair. The breaker would trip if current is exceeded. If you are touching the wires with breaker off when lightning strikes and it arcs dumps a charge you may also get zapped.in a normal house with breaker off and arc across contacts

Comment: **Hipot and leakage** are viable tests to verify flood damage.

Answer (score -1):

It is best to get it inspected and repaired by qualified Electrician.

My opinions are my own as an EE since 1975,  FYI only..

Ground Fault Interrupter (GFI or RCCD) type breakers will trip if the line and neutral current do not match within safe limits (xx uA). This implies the imbalance must be leakage to ground and does not mean current between line and neutral.  Thus is can detect leakage in wet lines.

If earth ground wire is also exposed near line neutral this serves as a good test for all wet cables for ground leakage or a safety leakage detection breaker circuit device. A DMM can be used to investigate problems.

### Other info

Line voltage with wires in pure water does not conduct much between the electrodes until it gets salty or dirty, then like vaporizers will boil the water.  Generally the current only passes between the exposed wires or breaker and will trip the breaker if excessive.  Current tends to follow the path of least resistance between the wires unless you happen to be grounded and between the wires or breaker contacts. ( not likely)

Depending on degree of contamination, it may need complete replacement.
A DMM can be used to measure any stray voltage on contaminated surfaces if wet. I would expect very high impedance (1M) ( low safe current.) But an aEE or Electrician can tell the difference.

There may be rare circumstances where the contaminants are not between line and neutral and between line and the plastic surface nearby making it more of a risk.   Consult an electrician if in doubt.

With all (most) the appliances off the power meter should be turning very slowly.  If they were contaminated but now dry, conditions of 100% humidity may later change the leakage current.  Normally it may burn off contaminants but in extreme cases may reduce the integrity of the insulation. Since the breaker box is grounded , it is safe and same with basement outlets but if still wet and dirty, turn off breakers or avoid touching near proximity of outlets or breakers.  (Wear dry safety gloves if in doubt if breaker handle is wet and corroded outside.)

When I had a basement flood I had the basement breakers turned off until I was sure it was dry and fortunately it was clean water.  Exposed wet phone lines often caused erratic behavior with audible white noise on line or phantom off hook, so the line was cut.    My Power issues were no drama, but the $1500 of water that pumped into the basement from a waterline break under kitchen sink for a month with no tenants and I was living out of town was a bit of repair work. But I fixed all the drywall and paint and sold it easily in 2 weeks.

### Personal experience

When you stand in electrified dirty water, one would be wise not to touch any earth ground.  But just standing in it is not a risk. Just like lightning 50 yards away into the lake where you are swimming will not electrify you but you may suffer blast effects.  Because the path of least resistance is not between you and the lake bottom its between the point of entry and the lake. I have been in metal boats near lightning strikes with no effects except for a tingle on the metal seismic wires I was touching and antenna effects picked up an ESD like event. ( I was a student doing seismic research on islands )
Did I say consult an electrician enough?  But I am EE since 1975.

Comment: Electrical current flows through all available paths.

Comment: yes but capacitance of water and resistance tends to have lowest imepdeance between electrodes or wires.  So the stray leakage is normally low.  but say it was salt water like in the Gulf, then you would need full repairs. The power meter will tell you if any current is flowing with breakers off , if you suspect the breaker panel is contaminated. A DMM is your friend to measure any stray leakage voltage.  10% on Neutral is normal

Comment: Current does not flow thru all available paths, Current only flows from exposed voltage / impedance path to nearest neutral or ground and gets attenuated quickly if everything is wet after that by series shunt attenuation to nearby earth ground. But your mileage may vary depending on proximity of earth ground paths.

Comment: Addition : The other issue with flooded breaker is there may still be dissolved salts within the mechanism when you turn the power back on that cause no bad effects electrically. However, as the salts dry they can cause the breaker to fail mechanically. That is.. glue closed. At which point, you no longer have a breaker.

Comment: Yes salt can make audible evaporation noises between wires like a "vaporizer" and your power meter may show. It is easily measurable.  Breaker failures can cause hot contacts with higher ESR and early wearout of contacts. Again a good EE or Electrician ought to know this by sensing excess heat off breakers with hand. Warm is normal under load, hot is not normal.  TY Trevor